# Stored procedure: how to check if NULL is present in postgresql array or not?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

array -  user_zoned_ids

```
IF NULL = ANY(user_zones_ids) THEN        
       Do Something
END IF;
```

But IF condition is always giving false even if NULL is present in array

Comment: `is null` instead of `= null` ?

Comment: Not working -  "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `ANY` operator to check for NULL values. You have to unnest the array and count the number of NULL elements:

```
if (select count(*) from unnest(user_zones_ids) as t(x) where x is null) > 0 then
   ... do something ...
end if;
```

Comment: I wish Postgres introduces `array.count(element)` someday.

Comment: little bit faster expression `select exists(select * from unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3, null]) g(v) where v is null);`